# Android slow query

Tags: android

In my main activity A, I have a button, when click, it will go to another activity B. when b on create, it queries from a table which is about 200 records and appends each record as textview into a ViewFlipper.

I have few problems. First, when the button in main activity is clicked, it takes about 3-5 seconds before go to activity B everytime.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Run some traceview to see what is slow, or manually add time stamps. It depends on how the query and schemes are setup, but if the count of the table is only 200, then the should maximum take a few milli seconds.

If it is the case that you create and layout 200 TextViews in onCreate, then i would think that is the reason for why it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Run your query in a separate thread or consider using asynquery ?

Answer (score 0):

I think AsyncTask or Thread are better option for getting the details. Show progressbar when doing background processing.

This example simulates your problem.
AsyncTask basic Example : [AsyncTask](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesother/239-android-application-and-asynctask-basics)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use asyncTask to get 200 records. It runs query in background